# PHP MySQLi function get user data can't work

Tags: php, function, mysqli

**i am using This code for showing user data record but this code is not work on my side**

I want to echo out specific user data. I created a function where I insert multiple arguments (each argument represents a column in the database) and then echo whichever column I want with a simple line of code.

Index.php

```
    include('function.php');
    $conn = new MySQLi(localhost, root, password, database);
    $user_id = $_SESSION['login_user']; // like 1
    $user = user_data($conn, $user_id, 'login', 'pass', 'nikename', 'email');

    if(empty($user)){
        echo 'error'; // always showing this error
    }else{
        echo $user['nickename'];    
    }
```

> Always Showing `echo 'error';`

```
function user_data($conn, $user_id){
    $data = array();
    $user_id = (int)$user_id;
    $func_num_args = func_num_args();
    $func_get_args = func_get_args();
    if ($func_num_args > 1) {
        unset($func_get_args[0]);
        unset($func_get_args[1]);

        $valid = array('login', 'pass', 'nikename', 'email');
        $fields = array();
            foreach($func_get_args as $arg) {
                if(in_array($arg, $valid)) $fields[] = $arg;
            }
            $fields = '`' . implode ('`, `', $fields) . '`';
            if($stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT $fields FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = ?")) {
            $stmt->bind_param('si', $fields, $user_id);
            $stmt->execute();
            //here I am trying to convert the result into an array
            $meta = $stmt->result_metadata();
            while ($field = $meta->fetch_field()) {
                $parameters[] = &$row[$field->name];
            }
            call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_result'), $parameters);
            while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                foreach($row as $key => $val) {
                        $x[$key] = $val;
                }
                $results[] = $x;
            }
            return $results;
            $stmt->close(); 
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing and analyzing your code several times, I think the below will solve your issue.

Add this before your while/fetch loop

```
$row = array();
stmt_bind_assoc($stmt, $row);
```

so your code will look like this

```
$row = array();
stmt_bind_assoc($stmt, $row);
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
     foreach($row as $key => $val) {
            $x[$key] = $val;
     }
     $results[] = $x;
}
```

Also make sure you read the full documentation of bind_param on php.net [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

Thanks and Best Regards

Comment: i already use `$stmt->bind_param('i', $user_id);` but code showing same result

Comment: can you print_r($results); in the function itself and see if you have any data? I would reverse the process and see at which point it's failing + add bin_assoc (edited my answer)

Comment: yes i check print_r($results) so there showing result `Array ( [0] => Array ( [login] => login [pass] => pass [nikename] => nikename ) ` but when i echo $user['nikename'] so showing error ... `Notice: Undefined index: user_login in C:\wamp\www\admin\template\home.php on line`

Answer (score 0):

I guess, instead of

```
if($stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT $fields FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = ?")) {
$stmt->bind_param('si', $fields, $user_id);
```

you should go with

```
if($stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT $fields FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = ?")) {
$stmt->bind_param('i', $fields, $user_id);
```

Bind parameters. Types: s = string, i = integer, d = double,  b = blob

As far as you have one argument with type INT you need to pass 'i' as a first parameters.

Try debugging over line by line in that function where you will get exact flaw by var_dump().